# ASP.NET Core Razor pages vs Full MVC Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

There has been a question at SO [Why is Razor Pages the recommended approach to create a Web UI in Asp.net Core 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777404/why-is-razor-pages-the-recommended-approach-to-create-a-web-ui-in-asp-net-core-2) where Steve Smith has kindly explained the benefits of using Razor Pages over full MVC from the perspective of having less files.

I've been using Razor Pages for a while and noticed that despite an advantage of a Razor Page simplicity, it is a bit complicated when it comes to custom routing, structuring folders and complex view model (page model seem to be cluttered).

So, the questions are:

1. If there is anything else except simplicity of a page to prefer Razor Pages over Controllers/Views - specifically I'm interested in performance of the two frameworks?
2. Is it acceptable to combine Razor Pages and Controllers/Views at the same time?

I would also appreciate if some of expirienced guys shared your thoughts (pros and cons) about using Razor Pages to better understand this framework.

Comment: I wouldn't mix the two. Just make the jump and try out full MVC yourself. It's not that complicated.

Comment: @Jasen thanks for the answer and sorry for being unclear. I've been using full MVC for the last 3 years and then Microsoft made this recommendation to use Razor Pages for UI applications. So, I would like to know if somebody has already began using the framework and approve that Microsoft's recommendation should be followed.

Comment: @IvanZaruba can you explain what was wrong with "structuring folders and complex view model (page model seem to be cluttered)"?

Comment: @S.Serp sure. I was unable to move _ViewStart, _Layout, _ViewImports to Shared folder; In case I wanted to group my pages within a folder (which is obvious) it affected page routing and the only way to override conventional routes was to configure RazorPagesOptions in Startup.ConfigureServices (unlike actions where I can decorate it with an attribute). In some cases I had big ViewModels with some VM-related logic inside; if I combined page's logic with a VM's logic and properties, the page looked ugly (seemed to violate SRP) unlike MVC models structure. All said is IMHO of course.

Comment: @S.Serp I'd rather stick to SPA + MVC (Web API) whenever possible. Still though, I think RazorPages suit better for small or CRUD-oriented projects (if no complexity evolution is supposed)..

Comment: @IvanZaruba thanks for your feedback. Also, I have added [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50793220/2803565) which specifies some points regarding the Razor Pages vs MVC based on an Microsoft doc: Razor Pages offer a significantly simpler means of building page-based application features, such as non-SPA forms, with similar performance...

Comment: @Jasen states I wouldn't mix the two. 
Why not? See https://github.com/Rick-Anderson/RP-vs-MVC/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Microsoft's stance on the two ([from the tutorial here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)) seems to be that Razor Pages is the better entry point for inexperienced ASP.NET Core developers, whereas MVC Core is the more flexible and configurable paradigm for veteran developers.

Comment: @RickAndMSFT `Hit F7 in Visual Studio to toggle between them`...I am new to ASP.NET and that little shortcut there for switching between a Razor page and its PageModel just sold me on using Razor pages more. It's always the little things :-)

Comment: @jasen writes: I wouldn't mix the two. That's bad advice. Microsoft mixes them. Create a new MVC app with authentication and scaffold Identity. All the auth code is Razor Pages.

Comment: @Extragorey why do you save * MVC Core is the more flexible and configurable*, that's not true.

Comment: @RickAndMSFT Simply because your tutorial starts out by saying, "If you're new to ASP.NET Core web development, consider the Razor Pages version of this tutorial, which provides an easier starting point." - which is also true in my experience, as Razor Pages keeps the business logic and rendering logic together via a code-behind file, whereas with MVC you need to familiarise yourself with models, views, and controllers (and actions, filters, view models, etc.).

Comment: @Extragorey I don't dispute it provides an easier starting point, but RP is just as flexible and configurable. We have lots of advanced customers using RP and many that mix them. There are reasons to choose MVC over RP, but flexibility/configurability is not two of them. I also disagree with keeps the business logic and rendering logic together via a code-behind file

Answer (score 85, accepted):

We've recently launched a pretty decent sized app using Razor Pages for the front end and MVC controllers for the API for client side components. My experience has been this:

The pages paradigm works well when your content is structured around the idea of actual "pages" on the site. Think about things such as a Contact Us or an About or even a Login page. Sure, those could be done via MVC, but MVC is really unnecessary. A simple page will suffice. Leave the controllers to more controller'ish things like a product catalog or a user database.

If your MVC architecture revolves heavily around your view structure, razor pages is probably a good fit. You can still use the MVC bits for API related stuff, but the benefit of pages is that your front end structure becomes more explicit and less implicit ("convention-based") like with MVC where each action could or could not have a view that is typically named after the action.

Comment: Chris, thank you for the valuable comment. Is this right that you mean it's ok to combine Razor Pages and API Controllers, but it's not for Razor Pages and traditional Views (served from Controllers)?

Comment: There's no real reason you couldn't combine the two. `/about` could be a razor page with company background info while `/users/1/profile` could be an mvc view that displays a user's info.

Comment: If `Asp.Net Core Razor Pages` is better than `ASP.NET Core MVC` than why did `Microsoft` released `ASP.NET Core MVC` ?  It seems folks [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/6146) like `MVC` style, Kindly guide us when we should use `ASP.NET Core MVC`  ?

Comment: @Chris I'm new to ASP.NET Core, how can I make a project both MVC and Razor Pages?

Comment: @OgrishMan Reference the nuget packages `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`

Comment: I'm not a fan of Razor Pages.. It reminds me too much of Web Forms.. With that said, you could definitely use both.. Heck.. in the past, when rewriting webforms apps to MVC we would basically deploy it in phases where half of the app was still in aspx webforms code behind files and the other half were mvc controllers and views.  So if you can do it back then you can certainly still do it now.

Answer (score 39):

Although Chris has provided a clear opinion on the frameworks being shipped with a standard ASP.NET Core Implementation. People must also note that for MS to recommend Razor Pages there's rather deeper reasons for that and they have been clear to me since I'm a big fan of razor pages.

> If there is anything else except simplicity of a page to prefer Razor
> Pages over Controllers/Views - specifically I'm interested in
> performance of the two frameworks?

To answer this, You sound like you simply haven't done a really heavy app in MVC if you're asking this question. Controllers become flocked with code, and it could be really messy, considering that not all programmers out there are following good programming practices(commenting and proper code management)... So imagine a controller with a few Page methods with logic all put in it. Well, the result is you'd easily end up with a controller consisting of over 400+ lines of code that could easily be split as it refers to different pieces of the app(pages or methods). So How about breaking those 300+ lines of code and separating them based on what they do? This is the whole idea behind razor pages. You only put code related to a specific page to it's own model rather than mixing code related to 10 pages in one file. Well, others could argue that you can create external classes where you'd put this logic to keep the controllers clean, but why go the extra mile? and secondly performance shouldn't be an issue at all. I don't think it matters at this point. Razor Pages thrives when it comes to form-based pages since model binding is so smooth with it.

> Is it acceptable to combine Razor Pages and Controllers/Views at the
> same time?

Well, MVC is the pinnacle of WebAPI's when it comes to .NET. So the two can be mixed at any point, anytime. Razor pages truly resemble "true pages" but they're flexible to fit anything, either a catalog or whatever you wish to build. each page can serve it's own requests GET, POST etc... so due to that you can do whatever you want with a razor page. It must also be clear that routing isn't complicated with Razor Pages. It works just as flexible as in MVC...

> I've been using Razor Pages for a while and noticed that despite an
> advantage of a Razor Page simplicity, it is a bit complicated when it
> comes to custom routing, structuring folders and complex view model
> (page model seem to be cluttered).

I'd rather disagree with this. Routing is flexible with Razor pages, you just haven't worked yourself around it. Also a razor page can build a very complex View because you can Bind as many View Models to it without any extra-effort required. With the annotation rule `[BindProperties]` or `[BindProperty]`, you can import as many fields you want into a view... and remember that the binding is Two-Way.

Unless you start working with Razor pages, you'll hear a lot of opinions about it, some will sway you away from using it, some like Chris will give you true feedback. But my advise is, Razor pages has evolved and performs best in any application of any size...

Comment: Came from MVVM background (WPF, Xamarin), I also like RP. I actually thought RP is MVVM for Web (still not sure if my assumption is true!)

Comment: @HassanTareq It is. RP is indeed a MVVM.

Comment: Controllers aren't supposed to become "flocked with code" because they're meant to have no business logic in them.  It seems to me like Razor Pages is kind of encouraging people to put business logic back in the presentation layer again, in a code-behind, after the industry has gone down the route of avoiding this with things like onion architecture and domain-driven design.  *sigh* how confusing...

Comment: No! Let me remind you that applications can become so complex that there's 70 different actions(think methods) relevant to a particular controller. What then? Are you really going to put implementations of those actions within the same controller? well... think about it. and you're also wrong by saying "Razor Pages is kind of encouraging people to put business logic back in the presentation layer again" Because a razor page model is simply an equivalent to a controller action method. So whatever you would do in action methods, applies to razor page models. It's up to you as the programmer.

Comment: Very good, honest and useful thoughts about RazorPages.

Comment: Just built a big project from scratch with Razor Pages. Loved it. I am loathe to go back to MVC if I can help it. I've experienced great big bloated controllers and not enjoyed it. Plus Razor pages seems to be orders of magnitude faster with .Net 6.

Comment: @NorbertNorbertson Every Microservice project I've developed in recent times were in RPs. RP is in many ways, better, in terms of developer experience compared to MVC.

Answer (score 12):

Chris and Mosia give good answers.  Chris writes

> You sound like you simply haven't done a really heavy app in MVC

I saw no significant advantage of Razor Pages (RP) over MVC with controllers and views when I ported [Get started with ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc) to [Get started with Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/). It wasn't until I ported [Get started with EF Core in an ASP.NET MVC web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro) to [Razor Pages with Entity Framework Core in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro) that I saw a significant productivity advantage. MVC/EF is by no means close to a real production app, it's much simpler. Yet it has enough complexity to demonstrate the advantages of RP over MVC.

In interviews with customers, the most common reason I hear for sticking with controllers and views for UI is that they have an existing controller/view code base.

The most common reasons for preferring RP over MVC is preventing bloated controllers and better integration between pages and views.

[Razor Pages vs ASP.NET Core MVC](https://github.com/Rick-Anderson/RP-vs-MVC) and
[Why choose MVC tutorials over Razor Pages](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/6146) provides more information and adds links to all the best **MVC VS. RP** content.

Much of the best comments in [Why choose MVC tutorials over Razor Pages](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/6146)  are hidden. Search for hidden and select **Load more...**

Comment: The linked GitHub issue is not a good resource for people trying to decide between full MVC and Razor Pages. The thread is full of MVC zealots spouting falsehood after falsehood about RP. To anyone who has used RP before, it's painfully obvious that these fundamentalists have never actually used RP. But, if you haven't used RP, they make it sound pretty awful. If I hadn't been using RP for over a year when I saw that thread, it would have been enough to scare me away.

Comment: One thing I love about RP is press F7 to toggle between the page and the code behind. Try that with MVC.

Answer (score 8):

I've been through the whole webforms, mvc, SPA life cycle with some enterprise sized apps. These are my thoughts:

- Webforms became too much abstraction over the html. Easy to use for simple demos but tricky to customize to the last tag.
- MVC was a break to that where everything is left to the developer. Idea was to separate everything and give back control to the developer. Unfortunately it also became a lot more complex and the simple page was scattered in three different locations (the model, the view and the controller). Removing functionality becomes tricky since it's in different places, hence people start to use feature folders to group all of the MVC components for a single feature.
- Razor pages is in my eyes a more standardized feature folder where they have merged the controller and the model to simplify life. I liked feature folders and I like the Razor pages for the same reason. It makes it easier to remove functionality when it's located in one spot and for larger solutions that is key. Simplifies workflow.

Comment: What are "feature folders" in asp.net core MVC, and how do you create them and what are the routing issues?  Do you mean Areas (they just overcomplicate even further)?

Comment: @Mike Yes, He meant Areas for feature folders.