# What is difference between View and Page in Asp.net core 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am new in Asp.net core 2. One of the new things in Asp.net core 2 are pages.
But I can't figure it out

1. What is difference between page and view?
2. What are the benefits of pages versus views?
3. In what cases should the page be used?
4. Can I use both at the same time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor pages vs Full MVC Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48121928/asp-net-core-2-0-razor-pages-vs-full-mvc-core)

Comment: @DavidG I think in this link just wrote about benefits of pages

Comment: But it's the same question.

Comment: [Why choose MVC tutorials over Razor Pages](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/6146) provides more information and adds links to all the best **MVC VS. RP** content.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Really, your question is what's the difference between a Razor Page and traditional MVC. Both utilize Razor views. A Razor Page is self-contained (sort of). It has a code-behind like a Web Form, so technically you'd have a `cshtml` and a `cshtml.cs` file, the latter of which would act as both your controller and your model. Whereas, with traditional MVC, you'd have separate `FooController`, `FooViewModel`, and `Foo.cshtml`. Aside from some slight functional differences (such as having to use convention-based "actions" like `OnGetAsync`, `OnPostAsync`, etc. with Razor Pages) that's pretty much it.

The chief benefit to Razor Pages, as I see it, is its self-contained nature. All the code regarding a particular piece of functionality is essentially all in one place. However, the downside to this is that it can make code reuse difficult or at least not as intuitive in some places. Personally, I think the clear division of responsibilities offered by MVC is the more ideal approach and its also less "magical". One of the marketing touchpoints of Razor Pages is that it's stupidly easy. That may be true, but it owes its "ease" to abstracting away things web developers should actually be cognizant of, and that can be dangerous. If you don't actually understand how something works, you won't know if you're doing things right.

I'm biased, but to honestly answer "When should Razor Pages be used?", I would say never. I don't like the mixing of responsibilities, all the "magic", etc. Since they were introduced the number of ASP.NET Core questions here have skyrocketed and the majority of the Razor Pages questions are about things that are either obvious or at least more intuitive with MVC. That said, if you *are* going to use them, they make the most sense on CRUD type stuff - things that don't have a lot of functionality and are fairly straight-forward and/or repetitive.

Finally, yes you can freely mix and match Razor Pages and MVC. However, it should be noted because it's not obvious to everyone: Razor Pages only work as Razor Pages when used as Razor Pages. In other words, if you create a view with a code-behind (a Razor Page) and then use that view as a return from an MVC action, a partial, etc., the code-behind isn't actually utilized, just the "view" portion. Actually, to be more accurate, it is "used" but only to provide the model for the view in a general sense, since the view uses the `Page` in the code-behind as its model. However, this won't actually be "active", in the sense that page actions won't be hit, things likely won't get initialized properly, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer is a good guide For beginners. Please tell if you know something else

Comment: Is your suggestion better to use the pages?

Comment: No. The opposite. I think Razor Pages are the rebirth of Web Forms and all the evils that went along with that. Still, they're not *quite* as bad as Web Forms were from a code perspective, and sparing use may not be too bad. However, I think MVC offers the better solution overall and leads to a better and more maintainable codebase.

Comment: @ChrisPratt "rebirth of web forms" - that's exactly my thought when I first saw it lol

Comment: @ChrisPratt your comments are typical of biased developers who have never done any non-trivial RP programming. All the evils is just wrong. See [Why choose MVC tutorials over Razor Pages](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/6146) provides more information and adds links to all the best **MVC VS. RP** content.

Comment: That's kind of my whole point, though. Things have changed since I posted this, and Microsoft now onboards with RP in the tutorials. That's fine, if you're an already established web developer.looking to start working with ASP.NET Core. However, if you're entirely new, it creates a false sense of ease. Everything is great and simple until it isn't, and frankly, the docs, while overall excellent, still drop you like a hot rock when it comes to anything much more advanced than basic CRUD.

Comment: My bias isn't against Razor Pages, it's against pushing a programming style that hides core web functionality developers should be aware of, even if they don't need to do it themselves. Razor Pages are fantastic for straight-forward content and CRUD, because of that abstraction, I use them myself for those.use cases. But, I've seen developers trying to manually return JsonResult from a custom handler, which is frankly just bad.

Comment: Seems to me this answer is just a whine. There is a difference between a View and a Page in ASP.NET Core. So what is it?

Comment: @ChrisPratt :  I like what you say.  Even with MVC there is a lot of magic that goes on and it is hidden from you. Now they bring in Razor Pages and hide even more from you.  

I am porting a large website from .net framework to .net core and I am bringing all my model view controllers.  I don't believe in relying on EF. Identity, roles  yes.  

Straight data to fill the screen?  No! If you can not query a DB you should be doing something else and not coding. EF dumbs down the programmer.  EF is all magic and when it breaks you have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: For adding an item to an ASP.Net Core web application VS 2022 has both _Razor Page_ and _Razor View_. I guess an answer to the question of the difference between them should be a different question if it does not exist.