# The right time to use razor pages vs mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to build an ecommerce website similar to amazon but the major difference is that users can register as companies and also register their own products within the website. I understand that mvc and razor web pages can be used side by side; I started a web application with razor web pages and it was stupidly easy to get up and running but now that I'm slightly further down the road (want to save users with different levels of permissions.) I beleive I may have to Transition my project

I've been reading some of the novel that is the microsoft documentation in addition to 3 other stack overflow links while researching.

[Why is Razor Pages the recommended approach to create a Web UI in Asp.net Core 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777404/why-is-razor-pages-the-recommended-approach-to-create-a-web-ui-in-asp-net-core-2?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor pages vs Full MVC Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48121928/asp-net-core-2-0-razor-pages-vs-full-mvc-core)

[What is difference between View and Page in Asp.net core 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50157934/what-is-difference-between-view-and-page-in-asp-net-core-2?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I was just hoping to get some good input on when is the right time to use a razor page. because as I read more stuff it seems like I need to go undo some stuff and transition to mvc.