# How to use partials to "get" stuff in asp.net-core razor pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, get, partials

I have the following partial located at `Pages/Partials/`

`Search.cshtml`:

```dotnet
@model SearchModel

<body>
    <form method="get">
        <div class="d-flex flex-row">
            <div id="search-div" class="form-group">
                <input asp-for="@Model.SearchString" value="@Model.SearchString" class="form-control" id="search-bar" placeholder="Enter ID" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

`Search.chshtml.cs`:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace AdminPortal.Web.Pages.Partials
{
    public class SearchModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public string SearchString { get; set; }
                
        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

`Home.cshtml.cs`:

```dotnet
@page "/Home"
@using AdminPortal.Web.Pages
@model HomeModel



<body>
    <partial name="Partials/Search" model="new Pages.Partials.SearchModel()" />
    <partial name="Partials/Map" model="new Pages.Partials.MapModel()" />
</body>
```

`startup.cs`:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace AdminPortal.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I click submit, it does not call the `OnGet()` method. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Manually add the form action:`action="/Partials/Search"` could be a solution.But actually if you do not specify the action,it also works well in my project.I think you need to find why caused not working in your project.Please share your Startup.cs. And please check if the request url in browser is `/Partials/Search` when you first render the search page.

Comment: Hi @d4rk4ng31,you could see that you add the `Partials/Search` as a paritial in the Home page,the request url should be `/Home`.And when you submit the form,it will go to the `/Home`,that is why you do not get into the search OnGet method.In your scenario,you have to specify the form action:`action="/Partials/Search"`.

Comment: Did you mind sharing your Home Page backend code?And where is your Home page located?In Pages folder or any othe folder?

Comment: @Rena. I am in the [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227566/discussion-between-rena-and-d4rk4ng31)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when I click submit, it does not call the OnGet() method.
> What am I doing wrong?

That is because partial view is a razor view instead of a razor pages.Razor view is just a view and it works with controller.More detailed explanation you could refer to:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50158395/11398810

The correct way is to add the backend code in your Home page:

Home.cshtml.cs:

```
public class HomeModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string SearchString { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {

    }
}
```

Search.cshtml:

```
@model HomeModel

<body>
    <form method="get">
          //...
    </form>
</body>
```

Or if you do not want to use the default OnGet method in Home page,you could use page handler:

Home.cshtml:

```
@page "/Home/{handler?}"  //change here
@using AdminPortal.Web.Pages
@model HomeModel

<body>
    <partial name="Partials/Search" model="new Pages.Partials.SearchModel()" />
    <partial name="Partials/Map" model="new Pages.Partials.MapModel()" />
</body>
```

Home.cshtml.cs:

```
public class HomeModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string SearchString { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {

    }
    public void OnGetSearch()
    {
       //do your stuff...
    }
}
```

Search.cshtml:

```
@model HomeModel

<body>
    <form method="get" asp-page-handler="Search">
        //...
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: All I had to do was use the `formaction` attribute.

Comment: As my first comment said,manually add formaction is a solution.But you need know why you make such error.Because the first time you change the formaction,you said it gives you 404.404 means do not find the page.That is why I consult a lot with you yesterday.

Comment: umm, but why doesn't it work with `action` attribute then?

Comment: You mean asp-action?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227622/discussion-between-rena-and-d4rk4ng31).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `action` value manually or set it via form tag helper methods like `asp-page`.

```
<form method="get" action="/Search">
</form>
```

Without an action value, the browser will send it to the current URL. This works fine when you have a page with a form and it should send it to the same page model, like GET (display the page) and POST, send the form.

However, with your partial - that is used across different pages - you need to specify the page by setting the correct URL.