# MVC architecture pattern in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I start learning asp.net core
and see that in the views file < razor pages > you always can using object @Model of ViewModel class in your view,
What I want to know that is kind of architecture pattern use here, is MVC or MVVM?

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand the question, but I think this might help with some confusion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48121928/asp-net-core-razor-pages-vs-full-mvc-core

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, I assume you want to know, whether the Asp.net Core Razor page's page model is an MVC architecture pattern or MVVM pattern, right? I suggest you could check [this article](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/pagemodel).

*The main purpose of the Razor Pages PageModel class is to provide clear separation between the UI layer (the .cshtml view file) and processing logic for the page.*

*A View Model is an implementation of the Presentation Model design pattern. It is a self-contained class that represents the data and behaviour of a specific "view" or page. The view model pattern is used extensively in MVC application development, where it mainly represents data, but typically little behaviour. In Razor Pages, the PageModel is also the view model.*

*Razor Pages is sometimes described as implementing the MVVM (Model, View ViewModel) pattern. It doesn't. The MVVM pattern is applied to applications where the presentation and model share the same layer. It is popular in WPF, mobile application development, and some JavaScript libraries. A main feature of MVVM is that the view is updated automatically to reflect changes to the underlying model. This process is usually controlled by two way binding and an implementation of the Observer pattern. In a server-side web application, the model resides on the server and the view is on the client. You need to implement additional complicated layers to achieve anything like the Observer pattern in such a distributed architecture.*