# ASP.NET: Core_WebApp vs. Core_WebApp (MVC) - .NET 6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I wanted to experiment a little with the new project templates in Visual Studio 2022 and noticed that there are 2 project types:

- ASP.NET Core Web App
- ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller)

When I visit the official ASP.NET website from Microsoft, I saw that they are promoting the non-mvc version, which resembles a little the WebForms at least with its code-behind logic.

So what's going on here? Is Microsoft silently deprecating the usage of MVC pattern?
If we start a brand new non-blazor web project, which way should we go? Which one is more future-proof? My question is merely based on the future plans of Microsoft and not on a debate, what architectural pattern we should use.

Comment: both are still MVC, the main difference is asp.net core is multi-platform, and does not require IIS to run.  If you create a core "MVC", then it is windows based, and not cross platform.  So, for the longer term future, choosing Asp.net core is the newer and better choice. but as noted, both asp.net core, and asp.net core MVC both still use MVC as the basic design approach.

Comment: @Albert: ASP.NET Core Web App is using a code-behind model approach and no controllers. How I see, it has nothing to do with MVC. (except deep down in source code library).

Comment: Ah, ok, I had assumed that both still use MVC. Happy to be corrected. By default, the core app does seem to create the controller folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that my question is already answered here:

[Why is Razor Pages the recommended approach to create a Web UI in Asp.net Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777404/why-is-razor-pages-the-recommended-approach-to-create-a-web-ui-in-asp-net-core)

and here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/porting-existing-aspnet-apps/comparing-razor-pages-aspnet-mvc

Comment: Please add your understanding of the differences between `ASP.NET Core Web app v. ASP.NET Core Web App (MVC)` in addition to the links.  Links may be removed at the source but your explanation will live here forever and help the community members who stumble on this SO post.

Comment: From those links and my understanding is ASP.NET Core Web App uses razor pages and seems to include code behind and view in a single CSHTML file where as the MVC version has the traditional model, view and controller.  I'm not sure but razor pages seem like classic ASP.NET to me with added routing, among others.